# Font-face and vertical position of text

Tags: position, font-face, padding, margin

I want to use After Disaster font on my website, but I can't achieve the same vertical position of displayed text in different browsers. Even more - it is dependent on system too. You may test this:

http://jsfiddle.net/z7rby/1/

On Linux Google Chrome displays text about one pixel higher than Firefox and Opera. On Windows Google Chrome displays it in the middle of background. What can I do with that?

Comment: You don't seem to be asking a question here.

Comment: I asked, "what can I do with that"? I mean how can I display it identically in all those browsers and systems.

Comment: 1. Compensate for the differences by writing browser-dependent CSS of course. Or, 2. Wait for all browser manufacturers to reach 100% compliance with the standards. Whichever is quicker.

Comment: I thought that problem my be with font and I can fix it manually. But I don't know where to start.

Comment: You can control your layout via positioning CSS e.g. width, height but not font rendering.

Comment: But can't I edit that font and make it somehow cross-browser?

Comment: Yes, good idea. Do that.

Comment: The problem is, I have no experience with typography. I think it should be possible (some of fonts are displayed correctly, right?), bu t I have no idea how font editors works:).

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to solve this problem. You have to accept that fonts will be rendered slightly differently on different systems, and find another way to achieve your visual goals.

You can control your layout via positioning CSS e.g. width, height but not font rendering.

If that level of control is not "good enough" then you can write browser-dependent CSS (tutorials exist online) to compensate for differences.

But please remember the goal in all computing is "good enough": Perfection is not cost-effective!

Once you have achieved a level where further improvements require a certain effort, but there are more important things to spend that effort on, that is the point when you have finished.

Comment: I converted TTF in Font Squirrel and it looks ok now.